# How to take a longer time frame in the time range in t-sql

Tags: t-sql

I need to count records between some range, but in the long term, for example:
I take range '2014-07-01' and '2014-07-21', but I need records only between 21:00:00 and 21:30:00...

```
Count(records) between '2014-07-01 21:00:00' and '2014-07-01 21:30:00'
Count(records) between '2014-07-02 21:00:00' and '2014-07-02 21:30:00'
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(records)
FROM [yourtable]
WHERE [timestamp] BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2014-07-02'
  AND CONVERT(TIME, [timestamp]) BETWEEN '21:00:00' AND '21:30:00'
```